# Передать список в запрос pymssql

Tags: python, python-3.6, pymysql

Пытаюсь сделать подобный запрос

```
a = [134567,12345,12468975]
c1.execute("select * from table1 where [Product ID] in (%s)", (a,))
```

Но возникает ошибка. При этом отлично работает если передаю переменную int
Как передать список значений?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте составить строку с разделителями:

```
items = [134567,12345,12468975]
sql = "select * from table1 where [Product ID] in (%s)"
sql = sql % ','.join(['%s'] * len(items))
c1.execute(sql, tuple(items))
```

В `%s` попадет: `%s,%s,%s` и получится `select * from table1 where [Product ID] in (%s,%s,%s)`, а сами элементы расположатся в свои `%s`

Comment: Все таки необходимо передать видимо список  инт значений. данный код выдает ошибку b"Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '66355,12454,12367' to data type int.DB-Lib error message 20018, severity 16:\nGeneral SQL Server error: Check messages from the SQL Server\n")

Comment: @ДенисСтадник, похоже, `pymysql` экранировал строку, вот и не прокатило, поэтому сделал изменение самой sql под элементы

Comment: только нужно передать не list, а tuple

Comment: @ДенисСтадник, не должна быть разница, а так `c1.execute(sql, tuple(items))`. Вы передали список и у вас была ошибка?

Comment: Да при передаче списка была ошибка

Comment: @ДенисСтадник, спасибо за отклик, поправил ответ